# Render to a particular section having a specific "id" in page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rendering

I making a website which asks users to register to an event. The register page has lot of other things and the register form is like in the middle of page. the code look something like this:

```
 <section id="section1" class="cd-section">   
  <div class="pagination-centered">  
   . 
   .
   .   
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="section2" class="cd-section">   
  <div class="container"> 
   .
   .
   .
   .
  </div>
 </section>

<section id="section4" class="cd-section">
 <div class="reg_form">
   <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> 
    . 
    . 
    .
 </div>
</section>
```

on unsuccessful registration my controller renders same page again, using:

```
 render('new')
```

now the page reloads and user find it on top of page (on section with id="section1"). so he has scroll down to form section to see what are the errors prevented him from saving.

Is there a way I can render page to section with id="section4"? or is there any way I can render page to a particular section of page using some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `anchor` directive in the `form_for` tag and you are done, try this

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {:action => "create" , :anchor => "form_anchor"} %>
```

On doing this you can use render as earlier, you don't have to modify anything in the action

Comment: thank you so much. that worked but would you care explaining what is anchor actually doing?